# Not able to change Tabbed Page's tab once modal is shown

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am facing issue with Tabbed Page in iOS. I have added 5 navigation pages in the tabbed page. After showing and closing modal, I am not able to change tab on tap. If I hold another tab for 3-4 seconds (long press) then that tab is getting selected. Not sure what is the issue. No logs as well.

The same code is working fine on Android. Please let me know if someone has faced a similar issue.

Home Page code

```
        private bool tabsConfigured = false;

        public HomeView (HomeViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
                On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarItemColor(Color.FromHex("#c1c1c1"));
                On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor(Color.White);
                On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(false);
                On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetOffscreenPageLimit(5);
            }
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0c293d");
                //this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
            }

            this.ViewModel = viewModel;
            this.ViewModel.SwitchTabAction = OnSwitchTabFromViewModel;

#if __IOS__
            InitTabs();
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
#if __ANDROID__
            InitTabs();
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            this.ViewModel.SwitchTabAction = null;
        }

        private void InitTabs()
        {
            var logService = AutofacUtil.Instance.Resolve<ILogService>();

            try
            {
                 if (tabsConfigured) return;

                this.Children.Add(this.GetInitialTabPage<DestinationsViewModel>("tab_guide", "Guide"));
                this.Children.Add(this.GetInitialTabPage<GroupsViewModel>("tab_chats", "Groups"));
                this.Children.Add(this.GetInitialTabPage<ItineraryViewModel>("tab_itineraries", "Itineraries"));
                this.Children.Add(this.GetInitialTabPage<ExpenseViewModel>("tab_expenses", "Expenses"));
                this.Children.Add(this.GetInitialTabPage<MoreViewModel>("tab_mores", "More"));
#if __ANDROID__
                this.BatchCommit();
#endif

                tabsConfigured = true; //Important to be here.

                //Setting Current Page
                if (this.ViewModel.ActiveTab >= 1)
                    this.CurrentPage = this.Children[this.ViewModel.ActiveTab];
                else if (this.ViewModel.ActiveTab == 0) //OnPageChanged doesn't get called for first tab.
                {
                    CurrentPage = this.Children[this.ViewModel.ActiveTab];
                    OnPageChanged();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logService.Error(ex);
            }
        }

        public NavigationPage GetInitialTabPage<T>(string icon, string title) where T : BaseCoreViewModel
        {
            Page page = new TabLoadingPage(typeof(T));

            NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(page);
            navigationPage.Icon = icon;
            navigationPage.Title = title;
            navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0c293d");
            navigationPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;
            return navigationPage;
        }
```

Code to show Modal. Calling PushModalAsync to show modal.

```
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        private INavigation _mainNavigation = null;
        private INavigation _currentTabNavigation = null;
        private INavigation _currentModalNavigation = null;
        private NavigationPage _currentModalNavPage = null;

        public void SetMainXamarinFormsNavigation(INavigation navigation)
        {
            _mainNavigation = navigation;
        }

        public void SetTabXamarinFormsNavigation(INavigation navigation)
        {
            _currentTabNavigation = navigation;
        }

        public async Task PushAsync<T>(object parameters = null, bool animate = true) where T : BaseCoreViewModel
        {
            var page = ViewCreator.CreateViewAndViewModelAndCallInit<T>(parameters);

            INavigation currentNavigation = null;
            if (_currentModalNavigation != null)
                currentNavigation = _currentModalNavigation;
            else if (_currentTabNavigation != null)
                currentNavigation = _currentTabNavigation;
            else if (_mainNavigation != null)
                currentNavigation = _mainNavigation;

#if __IOS__
            var currentPage = currentNavigation.NavigationStack.ElementAt(currentNavigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1);
            var oldTitle = currentPage.Title;
            currentPage.Title = "Back";
#endif
            await currentNavigation.PushAsync(page, animate);

#if __IOS__
            currentPage.Title = oldTitle;
#endif
        }

        public async Task PushModalAsync<T>(object parameters = null, bool animate = true) where T : BaseCoreViewModel
        {
            if (_mainNavigation == null) return;

#if __ANDROID__
            var emptyPage = new FirstEmptyNavPage();
#endif
            var startPage = ViewCreator.CreateViewAndViewModelAndCallInit<T>(parameters, true);

#if __ANDROID__
            _currentModalNavPage = new NavigationPage(emptyPage);
#else
            _currentModalNavPage = new NavigationPage(startPage);
#endif

            _currentModalNavPage.Popped += _currentModalNavPage_Popped;
            _currentModalNavPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0c293d");
            _currentModalNavPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;

#if __ANDROID__
            await _currentModalNavPage.PushAsync(startPage);
#endif

            await _mainNavigation.PushModalAsync(_currentModalNavPage, animate);

            if (_currentModalNavPage != null)
                _currentModalNavigation = _currentModalNavPage.Navigation;
        }

        private async void _currentModalNavPage_Popped(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_currentModalNavPage != null && _currentModalNavPage.CurrentPage is FirstEmptyNavPage)
            {
                _currentModalNavPage.Popped -= _currentModalNavPage_Popped;
                _currentModalNavPage = null;
                _currentModalNavigation = null;
                await _mainNavigation.PopModalAsync(false);
            }
        }

        public async Task PopAsync(bool animate = true)
        {
            if (_currentModalNavigation != null && _currentModalNavigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
                await _currentModalNavigation.PopAsync(animate);
            else if (_currentModalNavigation != null && _currentModalNavigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
            {
                await _currentModalNavigation.PopModalAsync(animate);
                _currentModalNavigation = null;
            }
            else if (_currentTabNavigation != null)
                await _currentTabNavigation.PopAsync(animate);
            else if (_mainNavigation != null)
                await _mainNavigation.PopAsync(animate);
        }

        public async Task PopModalAsync(bool animate = true)
        {
            if (_currentModalNavigation != null)
            {
                await _currentModalNavigation.PopModalAsync(animate);
                _currentModalNavigation = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to share code without it we would just be throwing hypothesis at you

Comment: @G.hakim Added code for the reference.

Comment: why have you added await async  ? The UI operations occur on the main thread which is awaited automatically.

Comment: @pooja which method you are taking about?

Comment: public async Task PopModalAsync(bool animate = true)

Comment: _currentModalNavigation.PopModalAsync is async thats why